# #N/A returned for IMPORTXML for meta tags initially

Tags: xml, import, google-sheets

I am trying to import social media data for different clients to keep up with likes, posts, etc. Originally I thought the formula wasn't working but 10 minutes later, upon reopening the Google sheets file, I noticed the data was now available. Can someone show me what I may be doing wrong?

My sample url is in cell A1:

```
https://www.facebook.com/EyeBeholdBeautyMUA/
```

and my formula is:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//meta[@name='description']/@content")
```

All the tutorials online say this should work fine, but for some reason the initial response is "#N/A".

Comment: This happens to me too, when I visit the site or edit the URL to something else and then back, it works again... Maybe the sites blocks the automatic parse?

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that you aren't doing something wrong.

IMPORTXML as well as other import functions sometimes doesn't work.

This could occur because the import task exceeds the maximum execution time, the Google servers can't reach the source URL, etc.

By the way, the formula work fine for me.

Related

- [.getValue() return #N/A when reading ImportXML cell sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14317226/1595451)
- [Google Spreadsheet xpath scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28759544/1595451)
- [suddenly importxml #n/a error import content is empty appear](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46443061/1595451) (unanswered)